# Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick restricts double click

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code that inserts a new row (then copies formulas) upon double-click in a certain sheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Cancel = True
Dim Msg As String, Ans As Variant
Msg = "Add a row below?"
Ans = MsgBox(Msg, vbYesNo)
Select Case Ans
    Case vbYes
    Target.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
    Target.EntireRow.Copy Target.Offset(1).EntireRow
    On Error Resume Next
    Target.Offset(1).EntireRow.SpecialCells(xlConstants).ClearContents

    Case vbNo
    GoTo Quit:
End Select
Quit:
End Sub
```

This however replaces my double-click feature so that I can no longer edit cells directly (like you can normally do when you double click a cell). Is there a way to retain both functionalities of double click? Maybe if I click "No", then it selects the cell in edit mode?

Would appreciate any pointers

Comment: `Cancel = True` is the line which overrides the normal behaviour so move that.

Comment: Put Cancel=true a few lines below in case vbyes and delete the one on top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first line:

`Cancel = True`

It says: I don't want the default double click action (cell edit mode) to occur

Simply change it to `Cancel = False` and move to proper place.